# Existence of Inverse Mapping : $f: \;P(\Bbb R) \rightarrow \Bbb R $ where $f(x) = {1\over x^2}-x\cdot arctanx+{1 \over 2}log(1+x^2) $

Tags: inverse-function

I'd like to show that below function holds the inverse mapping:

$f: \;P(\Bbb R) \rightarrow \Bbb R $ where $f(x) = {1\over x^2}-x\cdot arctanx+{1 \over 2}log(1+x^2) $

To show the existence of inverse mapping, I want to use the property that every inverse mapping has a bijection between domain and range of its orignial function.

But each term of $f(x)$ holds different domain and range which makes this process cubersome.

Any brief approach to check the inversibility of the given function?

Comment: What is  $P(R)$?

Comment: @$P(\Bbb R) = \{x \in \Bbb R\mid x > 0\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints (Every monotone function has a inverse mapping):

Since $$f'(x)=-\frac{1}{x^3}-\arctan x,$$
we can conclude that $f'(x) > 0$ whenever $x<0$; $f'(x) < 0$ whenever $x>0$, which leads that $f(x)$ has a inverse mapping.

Comment: thx. it's not a hint but contains every reasoning what I need. Any reference that denotes well-proved statement of "Every monotone function has a inverse mapping"?

Comment: @Daschin You are welcome! Every monotone function has a inverse mapping, because every monotone function is one to one.

Comment: note that function is Even, which means $f(x) = f (-x)$ for all $x \in R$ so $f: R \to R$ is not one-to-one! it is monotone on $(0 , + \infty)$  or $( - \infty , 0)$ but not both..   @Daschin